# on Samsung phones, unlike other android devices, the code presented below does not work, why?

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-mobile, onkeylistener

I create a restriction on entering text in the EditText field via OnKeyListener. This code works on all other devices except Samsung.

For some reason, the output of key codes on the Samsung device does not work.

Need to edit real-time input.

```
massEditText.setOnKeyListener(object: View.OnKeyListener{
            override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean
            {
                Mark.setText(event.action.toString())
                if(event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    provider.setText(keyCode.toString())
                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                        return false;

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0 && Mass.text.toString().length < 1)
                        return true


                    val number: String = (keyCode - 7).toString();

                    if(Mass.text.toString().length > 0)
                    {
                        var resultNumber: String = "";
                        for(i in Mass.text.toString())
                        {
                            resultNumber+=i;
                        }
                        resultNumber+=number;
                        if(resultNumber.toInt() !in 1..40)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean in this context? Exception? Wrong value? Always the same value? Some arbitrary / random value? ...

Answer (score 0):

That's because as per [this document's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html#onKey(android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) `setOnClickListener` only works when hardware key press. 
I wonder because this code is working on other devices. I don't know why.

So, you can use `addTextChangeListener` instead of `setOnClickListerner` to resolve this issue.

Try and let me know this works or not. 
Thanks.

Comment: I have already tried TextChangeListener and it does not allow editing the line I need directly at the moment of its input. Moreover, this code does not work exclusively on Samsung devices.

Comment: So, exactly you want to perform some action when text is changed in edit text right?

Comment: And it shows you want to add restriction in edit text. what kind of restriction it is?